# Optimizing geographical SQL query

Tags: sql, optimization

I wrote a SQL Query that gets me the names of cities with airports on specific longitudes and latitudes. Is it possible to write this more efficiently (for example without Union or the subqueries I have used)?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    C.Name 
FROM 
    Cities C 
WHERE 
    C.CityID IN (SELECT A.CityID FROM Airports A 
                 WHERE A.Latitude < 10 AND A.Longtitude < 5 
                   AND C.CityID = A.CityID 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT A.CityID FROM Airports A 
                 WHERE A.Latitude > 50 AND A.Longtitude > 100 
                   AND C.CityID = A.CityID)
```

The schemas I am using for the cities is:

```
CREATE TABLE Cities
(
     CityID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
     UNIQUE Name
);
```

and the schema for the airports are:

```
CREATE TABLE Airports
(
     IATA CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
     Name VARCHAR(256),
     CityID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Cities(CityID),
     Latitude DECIMAL NOT NULL,
     Longtitude DECIMAL NOT NULL,
     Altitude SMALLINT,
     UNIQUE (Name, CityID)
);
```

Comment: ... that seems like a very strange set of lat/long bounds to use (it's not a "rectangle" on a standard mercator projection map).  Are you sure that's what you intended?  If your RDBMS supports GIS or shape queries (SQL Server, Postgres too I think, maybe others), would a "within x miles" query be more appropriate?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exists`.  For efficiency, I would recommend `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT C.Name 
FROM Cities C 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Airports a
              WHERE a.CityId = c.CityId AND
                    ((a.latitude < 10 AND a.longitude < 5) or
                     (a.latitude > 50 AND a.longitude > 100)
                    )
             );
```

You want an index on `Airports(CityId, latitude, longitude)` for this query.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, i am not sure if i understood this correctly but is it also possible to do all of this entirely without subqueries?

Comment: @David . . . The `EXISTS` subquery is likely to be more efficient because you don't have to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach to avoid sub-queries, but I agree that Gordon's approach with `EXISTS` is the most efficient query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Name
FROM Cities C
    INNER JOIN Airports A
        ON a.CityId = c.CityId
WHERE A.Latitude < 10 AND a.Longtitude < 5
    OR a.Latitude > 50 AND a.Longtitude > 100
```